# I'm trying to plug in Euler method in Matlab but keep getting "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Tags: matlab

This is my code for `Euler method` but I keep getting

> Error :"Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
>   logicals."

```
%Define parameters                                                           
A=1250; %m^2         
Q=450; %m^3/d                                                             
a=150;           
y(i)=0;          
t(i)=0;               
t=[0:0.5:10]';                              
%Set loop in (Eulers method) for the amount of steps we want to do to
%find our estimated solution                            
for i=1:20               
y(i+1)=y(i)+((3*(Q/A)*sin(t(i)).^2)-(a*(1+y(i)).^1.5/A))*0.5                  
end                    
%generate table for data             
disp('t            y')                     
disp('---------------')                 
disp([t,y])                      
y=y'                       
plot(t,y)                                 
title('Plot of y vs t')                                  
xlabel('time')                            
ylabel('y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `y(i)=0` and `t(i)=0`
Did you mean to say:
`y(1)=0;
t(1)=0;`

Since you define `t` in the next lines don't even bother defining the 1st index of t, `t(1)`

So remove line 6
`t(i) = 0`
And change line 5:
`y(i)`to`y(1)`